# Command with input redirection inside while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop, command-substitution

I am trying to loop inside a text file containing commands to be executed:

```
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
      $line
    done < msmtp-cmds.txt
```

The commands inside the text file are:

```
  msmtp -t < message1.txt
  msmtp -t < message2.txt
```

After command substitutions the redirection sign seems to be ignored, as msmtp is trying to use message1.txt as a recipient, but I cannot figure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<` is not an argument to the command; it's shell syntax that is parsed *before* parameter expansion. If your intent is to execute arbitrary code read from a file, that's what `eval` is for.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  eval "$line"
done < msmtp-cmds.txt
```

However, at that point, you may as well just source the file rather than reading it line by line:

```
. smtp-cmds.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion about using `eval` solves my problem. As for just sourcing the file, I will have to write a simple logic based on the result of each `msmtp` command: if the mail messages are not sent for any reason, the script must be terminated.